# Can I install anaconda on linux in a hidden folder?

Tags: python, anaconda, data-science

Can i set the path in the anaconda installer to `$ /home/.anaconda` ?

When it will get added to the `PATH` will it lauch ?

Comment: Have you tried it?  If so, what are the issues?  I suggest trying it first.  Worst case, just `rm -rf /home/.anaconda`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. 
But you may have to manually run:

`$ source <path to conda>/bin/activate`

`$ conda init`

and after that it worked.